# How to check that a string does not contain "bird" or "cat" with a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, expression

Please don't tell me about use the boolean `!` to check it. Because I want to use a jquery plugin to do something in my function. And I want to fix it only regex section... Is that possible?

Comment: Could you please to the time to rephrase your question in a way that is orthographically correct?

Comment: Is the regex done by javascript or php?

Comment: By original regex language. can be possible to check this case ?

in a textbox can be insert everything except string 'dog' and even if i'm insert 'dog1234' it will be ok to pass!.

Answer (score 6):

Better, IMO:

```
preg_match('/^(?!.*(cat|bird).*$)(......)/xs', $string);
```

Comment: @tchrist I didn't know. The questioner uses PHP, but me, I only know Python well. I went to the PHP manual and read the explanation concerning /x but at that moment I didn't understand very well, so I thought that the "best" was to write options /xs as in the mario's answer. - Now I've read again the explanation and I understand that it's similar to the VERBOSE flag in Python that allows to write commentaries inside the RE. If no commentaries are wished in this RE, /x is useless indeed, you are right

Answer (score 2):

You can use this assertion/negative assertion construct to check that the whole string does not contain `bird` or `cat`:

```
preg_match('/(?=^((?!cat|bird).)+$)  (......)/xs', $string);
```

I assume it is not particularly efficient. But at least the asssertion is independent from the actual match regex - as example `(......)` here.

Comment: this case i could not use 'preg_match' because i'm not use php.

Comment: Try it out with `new RegExp('/..../')` in Javascript. I'm not sure if JS regexp does support both assertion types though. (If it doesn't work then you won't get around using a normal `!` test..)

Comment: this case i could not use 'preg_match' because i'm not use php. I mean to when i typing in textbox and then RegEx check i mean to whatever some word excepting 'cat' or 'bird' unless I'm insert cater it should be passed to. now is code in Jquery js script , i have one line to edit by using only RegEx language. like this                 

"alertBox": {
                    "regex": /\b(?!cat|bird)\  //i don't know what user fill to textbox and i exactly has to string user can't type into that is "cat" or "bird"
 
                    "alertText": "Break! BS, you r Cat or Bird!"
                },

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is more simple and less confusing;

```
$string = ", user, test, me";
if (!preg_match("#(.*?)(cat|bird)(.*?)#", $string)) {
    echo "yes, there is no cat or bird";    
}
else{
    echo "there is cat or bird";
}
```

I would recommend you to check it here http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html